# SQL join - displaying data where partial result contains a null column

Tags: sql

I am writing the following stored procedure in mssql.

The columns foo and bar are in table1 and id is in table2.

```
select foo, bar, id from table1
join table2 on table2.foo = foo.foo
```

My issue is that if there is only data for foo and bar I want it to return

a, b, null

However it will not return a row at all if id doesn't exist but foo and bar do.

Is there an elegant way to make this work?

Comment: ah thats what that's for thanks it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
SELECT foo, bar, id FROM table1
OUTER JOIN table2 on table2.foo = foo.foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a `FULL OUTER JOIN` query

```
SELECT a.foo, a.bar, a.id 
FROM table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 b 
ON a.foo = b.foo
```

You can have a check to this [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)